# How to make JavaScript webpage look like an app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, javascript

I want to make a simple webpage with a JavaScript game look like an app on the iPhone. I know I can save a bookmark to the homescreen and that looks like an app and I know I can set the apple-itouch-image for the thumbnail in my HTML. But when you click on the app on the homescreen, it's clear this is just a webpage. How can I get rid of the URL and search bar at the top like Google Reader does? It's fine to see that bar if you later scroll up.

Is it possible to dive right into full-screen mode when the webpage is clicked?

I'm not looking for anything like PhoneGap, I just want to make a simple webpage with JavaScript look like an app, I don't want it to actually be an app.

Comment: Your best bet would be to look at http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put some meta tags in your head block of the page. Try these:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

`viewport` sets width and controls scaling and zooming.

`apple-mobile-web-app-capable` informs the Apple iOS that the application can be installed to the users springboard so that it starts the Safari Mobile browser without a menu bar

`apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` controls the look of the thin status bar at the top of the screen.

Another useful line is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="myicon.png"/>
```

Which will give the app a custom icon once installed.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Except that the `black-translucent` status bar doesn't work on my iPhone 4s, it's just plain black. I even looked up the correct usage in Apple's docs. Maybe that feature was discontinued...

Comment: I believe you need commas instead of semicolons on the values for content on viewport.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a few `<meta>` tags, most notably `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`. See a full tutorial here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Then it should work after it was saved to homescreen.